# CartThrob 2 lite

Tags: cartthrob, ecommerce

I am seeing some info on CartThrob 2 Lite at http://cartthrob.com/docs/docs_cartthrob-lite/
but no pricing or info on how to obtain it.

1) Anyone here have a pre-sale email address for the makers
MightyBigRobot?
(I am only seeing a phone number for purchased product support.)

2) I presume it costs less, but the documentation makes me wonder
if it only can handle one single item being sold on a site.
Anyone know?

Thank you.

TMV

Comment: Hi TMV. For future questions could you post 1 question per post please? It helps for discoverability and encourages better answers. http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222741

Comment: To Andrew Failie  - good suggestion, will keep to 1 question per post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CartThrob support team doesn't seem to be actively monitoring StackExchange recently, but they do seem to respond to their Twitter feed more regularly.  You might want to try asking them there:

https://twitter.com/cartthrob/with_replies

If you still get no love, then you could also try scheduling a callback/chat through their support system, which has been pretty reliable in my limited experience:

http://support.mightybigrobot.com/

Answer (score 1):

Answer to part 1) of the question:

Thanks to Positlux's suggestion, I have confirmed via past Mighty Big Robot tweets that they by policy provide no email address for pre- or post-sale support.
They want you to tweet them.
After three tries, (one tweet a day over the past three days)
I have learned that CartThrob Lite is not available, but they hope to make it available again:

My tweet:

@cartthrob Is CartThrob Lite still available? Not seeing where to get it or the cost.

Tweeted answer back from Mighty Big Robot:

"Hi, no sorry, not right now. Should be back in the near future."

On part 2) of the question, I have scheduled a phone call for next week (Mighty Big Robot free support phone calls are available 3 days a week). Will report here what I learn.

Comment: Follow-up: Received support call confirmation emails. Called on time. Put on hold, no human answered, was then disconnected. Now see email sent ~3 min before call time."Hello Tom,
CartThrob Lite is no longer available.
The main difference between CartThrob Lite and CartThrob was that CT Lite contained no shopping cart system. It was basically a single page checkout for taking donations or selling a single product. We discontinued selling it, like many of our products, so we could concentrate on developing and supporting our main product, CartThrob.

Thanks for your inquiry.
-Chris Barrett

Answer (score 0):

I presume it was removed (temporarily?) as per this post:

http://cartthrob.com/docs/docs_support/

(This is a list of products that Mighty Big Robot has stopped offering for purchase. CartThrob Lite is *not* in the list.)